# How can I set up `has_many` condition in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

User
 - last_active_at (last sign in time)

Community
 -user_id

Code
 -user_id
 -community_id

1. User has_many communities & codes
2. Community belongs_to user, has_many codes
3. Code belongs_to user & community

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many :communities
has_many :codes, :dependent => :destroy
```

**models/community.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
has_many :codes
```

**models/code.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :community, counter_cache: true
```

I can retrieve all the communities by coding like this with the gem called ‘acts_as_votable’ (https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)
```

Then I’m trying to retrieve all the codes under those all @communities.

```
@codes = Code.includes(:user).where(:community_id => @communities.collect(&:id)).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

But I want to sort it ordered by User table’s `last_active_at` column. 
So I tried this below

```
@codes = Code.includes(:user).where(:community_id => @communities.collect(&:id)).order("users.last_active_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

But it takes forever to load.

Is the best solution probably to make `has_many` condition between Community and User through Code?
Then it should be something like this.

```
@codes = @communities.code_group.include(:users).order("users.last_active_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

How can I change my code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change the `has_many` on the `User` model to `has_many codes, through: :communities`.  Then `Code` should only `belongs_to :community`. This is unless `Users`'s can have `Codes` without the `Code` being associated with a `Community`

Comment: what if user doesn't bwlong to community but has code for that community?

Comment: By not belong you mean it doesnt have a record in the database for that user/community combination?

Comment: no. User can belong to communities, and it's handled  by using the gem called "acts_as_votable" as I stated in my qustion. So it's totally separated from thi code table.